# styled components : using css to add colour based on values

Tags: css, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6, styled-components

I have a dropdown component that looks like this

[image]

Sourcecode :

```
const DropdownSelectPriority = props => {
  const { multiChoiceArray } = props
  return (
    <ButtonContainer>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => {
        return (
          <div key={questionChoice.id}>
            <p>{questionChoice.text}</p>
            <SimpleSelect
              placeholder="Select a priority"
              onValueChange={value => console.log(value)}
            >
              {questionChoice.options.map(options => {
                return <option value={options.label}>{options.value}</option>
              })}
            </SimpleSelect>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </ButtonContainer>
  )
}
```

I would like to style my div based on the values chosen, How can I achieve this? For example, if water quality management is the highest priority I would like to add some styles etc

Comment: Did you try to read the docs? It's basically the main feature of styled-components

Comment: Yeah I did, but I wasn't sure how to apply a style for each `{options.value}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style a generic `Option` with background property:

```
const Select = styled.select`
  background: ${({ bg }) => bg};
`;

const Option = styled.option`
  background: ${({ bg }) => bg};
`;

const options = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('red');
  return (
    <Select
      value={selected}
      onChange={e => setSelected(e.target.value)}
      bg={selected}
    >
      {options.map(option => (
        <Option key={option} value={option} bg={option}>
          {option}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit boring-hypatia-d16c1]

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I'm after...what if I wanted `background: palevioletred;` to be dynamic instead of the dropdown item?

Comment: So add a state to it

Comment: Why is state necessary? In your codepen you aren't using state for `{option}` to use the dynamic colors

Comment: It's not necessary, you can use a reference too, its not a styled-component problem from now, it's simple react.

Comment: I added an example with state